# Inheritance on a constrained generic type parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I know it isn't possible to inherit from a generic type parameter, but it would be handy when implementing a common proxy for derivatives of an abstract type :-)

Does anyone know why this isn't possible?

Example C#:

```
abstract class Foo
{
  public virtual void Bar()
  {
     // nop
  }
}

class FooProxy<TFoo> : TFoo
  where TFoo : Foo
{

  public override void Bar()
  {
    // do some stuff before
    base.Bar();
    // do some stuff after
  }

}
```

EDIT: Some more code to illustrate an example of how this could be used. Consider the following derivatives of Foo:

```
class FooX : Foo
{
  public string X { get; set; }
  public override void Bar()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Doing Bar X");
  }
}

class FooY : Foo
{
  public string Y { get; set; }
  public override void Bar()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Doing Bar Y");
  }
}
```

And the calling code:

```
FooProxy<FooX> fooXProxy = new FooProxy<FooX>();
fooXProxy.X = "test X";
fooXProxy.Bar();

FooProxy<FooY> fooYProxy = new FooProxy<FooY>();
fooYProxy.Y = "test Y";
fooYProxy.Bar();
```

The code in the FooProxy override of Bar() method will be reused when using FooX and FooY.

EDIT: Revised as per Pete OHanlon's answer: made Bar() method virtual.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Because you can't. Generics are not templates. You shouldn't think about them like C++ templates and expect the same behavior. They are fundamentally different concepts.

The C# specification explicitly prohibits usage of type parameters as base class:

> #### C# 3.0 Language Specification: Type Parameters (§4.5)
>
> A type parameter cannot be used directly to declare a base class (§10.2.4) or interface (§13.1.3).

#### Update:

I understand what you want to do and its use. This is a traditional use case of C++ templates. Specifically, if this was possible to do using C# generics, things like [`Moq` library](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) could benefit from it. The problem is, C++ templates are compile time "find and replace" constructs while C# generics are a run time thing.

To demonstrate this fact, for this class:

```
class Test<T> where T : class {
    // whatever contents it might have...
}
```

only a single IL will be emitted at compile time and at run time, the JIT compiler would generate a **single** native code for all reference-type type parameters. This is not like C++ templates at all, where native code would be emitted for every `T` separately (it's subject to optimization but conceptually, they are completely separate pieces of code).

Comment: I want the upvote, but I think your on the money, C++ templates aren't C# generics...

Comment: In other words, it's impossible for an object to conform to both the derived generic class binary layout (which requires the base subobject to be a fixed, consistent size) and the base class binary layout.  The "fixed size base" requirement is imposed by the CLR, and is not fundamental -- one could store offsets to each of the subobjects, and this is what is also needed in languages that support multiple virtual inheritance -- but .NET chose to avoid that additional complication.

Answer (score 8):

You can't inherit from a generic type parameter because the type isn't known at compile time so the compiler can't figure out what the superclass is. I realise that, at first glance, the fact that the compiler can figure out what <T> is would seem to suggest that it should be able to figure out what T is, but the two things are different.

Also, you have a logic problem in Bar. You can't call base.Bar because this is an abstract type. In order to correct this, you'd have to change your implementation in Foo to

```
public virtual void Bar() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because Foo is an abstract type.

If you implemented Foo in a class then used it at the template then you could do that.

You could also use an interface to do what you are trying to do I believe.

Edit:

On second thought looking at your code, it makes no sense.  You would need to create a base class of the **GENERIC** type, then derive from that to achieve what you are trying to do.  It would also make a hell of a lot more sense...

```
abstract class Foo<T>  
{  
    public virtual void Bar();  
}
```