# How to inherit from a generic parameter?

Tags: c#

I'm basically wanting to do this:

```
class UILockable<T> : T
    where T : UIWidget
{
}
```

However, this doesn't work. I've seen people recommend that you do this:

```
class UILockable<T>
    where T : UIWidget
{
    private T _base;
}
```

This would require me to override each function UILockable would need and forward it to T. This is impossible since T may derive from UIWidget and have unique abstract/virtual methods of its own.

Is there no way to simply inherit from T?

Comment: Consider forcing the generic type to implement a specific interface. You cannot know what exact type T is, and if you're looking for specific methods that any T may or may not have, it's not going to work. Make all such objects implement ILockable which forces those methods, like a contract.

Comment: If you don't need to override protected methods in order to accomplish your locking logic, you could redesign this using a locking service object that associates UIWidget instances with LockContext objects used for your locking logic.  I don't think inheritance is a good conceptual fit for what you're trying to do, as you're trying to generally augment functionality, not express a concrete 'is-a' relationship.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inheritance on a constrained generic type parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420581/inheritance-on-a-constrained-generic-type-parameter)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't inherit from the generic type parameter.  C# generics are very different from C++ templates.  Inheriting from the type parameter requires the class to have a completely different representation based on the type parameter, which is not what happens with .NET generics. They are identical at the IL and native level (for all reference type arguments).

Answer (score 4):

Think about it this way:
When Type *B* inherits from type *A*, you're declaring that *B* is *similar* to *A* (where similarity means that you can use *B* everywhere you expect to use *A*). Now because such similarity is not symmetric you have that *B* is similar to *A* but *A* is not similar to *B*. Furthermore, *B* and *C* can both be similar to *A* (i.e. they both descend from *A*) without being similar to each other.

So what you want to declare is that Unlockable is similar to everything that is similar to UIWidget, but that's impossible because type similarity is not transitive (i.e. if *B* is similar to *A* and *C* is similar to *A* you can't say *B* is similar to *C*).

Comment: @Robert Why this one is not the answer?

Comment: @AgentFire: Because it overlooks the essential point -- `Unlockable<T>` would be similar to `T`, not other subclasses of `UIWidget`, and it would be similar by virtue of inheriting the behavior from `T`.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not. However, I don't really understand your argument against having `UILockable<T>` inherit from `UIWidget` and forward all calls onto your `T`:

```
class UILockable<T> : UIWidget
    where T : UIWidget
{
    private readonly T t;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        this.t.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

You don't care about the specifics of `T`'s implementation of `UIWidget` - only that it *is* an implementation of `UIWidget`.

Comment: I think what he's saying is that if you do it this way, any methods of `T` that aren't specified by `UIWidget` won't be accessible.

Comment: In which case, you would need to add more generic constraints such that T extends UIWidget and implements some interfaces too.

Answer (score -1):

You can't inherit from a Generic type argument. C# is strictly typed language. All types and inheritance hierarchy must be known at compile time. .Net generics are way different from C++ templates.

And when you're so sure that type argument T is going to be of type UIWidget then why not inherit from UIWidget itself. Should it ever be allowed [assuming, just assuming, I know this will never be possible] what would you achieve by inheriting your class from T that is already of type UIWidget. At design time, you'll only code against UIWidget, so why not directly inherit from UIWidget.

Comment: Why not directly inherit from `UIWidget`?  *Mixins*.  Just because the mixin can only use the essential interface provided by `UIWidget`, doesn't mean that the consumer wouldn't like to have the mixin behavior and some more specialized widget behavior *on the same object*.

Comment: Being strongly statically typed and forbidding this inheritance are completely orthogonal.