# General interface inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

**Q:** Is it possible to use general interface inheritance in C# or maybe some other techniques to improve flexibility, as shown below?

```
public IAddSomeAdditionalBehavior<T> : T {
     void ToDoSometing()
}

public interface ICar {
    void Drive()
}

public interface IAirplane {
    void Fly() 
}
```

DI registration:

```
.AddScope<IAddSomeAdditionalBehavior<ICar>, CarWithAdditionalBehavior>
.AddScope<IAddSomeAdditionalBehavior<IAirplane>, AirplaneWithAdditionalBehavior>

public class CarWithAdditionalBehavior : IAddSomeAdditionalBehavior<ICar> {
    void Drive() {}
    void ToDoSometing() {}
}

public class AirplaneWithAdditionalBehavior : IAddSomeAdditionalBehavior<IAirplane> {
    void Fly() {}
    void ToDoSometing() {}
}
```

I believe it would be very convenient to have such syntax. Some kind of dynamic functionality extension.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible with generics. Generics are evaluated at runtime, whilst the inheritance hierarchy needs to be defined at compile time (in order for the type metadata to be built up correctly). This makes them different from C++ templates, which are evaluated at compile time. Templates are also where this pattern results from. Also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520219/is-it-possible-to-make-an-object-expose-the-interface-of-an-type-parameter) I've asked a while ago.

Comment: It's a pity ( ok got it - thanks a lot

Comment: @AllmanTool C++ templates are just one way to implement traits. C# has many more. In C# 8 (and Java 8, PHP) traits can be added on a type using [default-interface-members](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/). Or you can specify [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) separately to extend functionality without modifying the type itself

Comment: In fact, there's *no* need for such syntax on interfaces - why would the *interface* need to inherit from T? C++ needed that to avoid breaking the inheritance hierarchy. C# 2 also allows `MyExtension<T>:T` but that is frowned upon because it creates a bogus inheritance hierarchy and makes composition a *lot* harder. Extension methods can easily add extra behaviour without affecting inheritance.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: `public class MyExtension<T> : T { }` won't compile. Also it shouldn't, since this would leave the class hierarchy undeductable, breaking the `Type` system. Or did I misunderstand your comment?