# How to return a property of the class instead of the class itself?

Tags: c#, class, casting, operator-keyword, implicit

I'm currently converting and casting from Class to `Class2` using the implicit operator.

But what I want to do is, that, whenever I refer to **`foo (Class<Class2>)`**, I'd like for **`Goo(Class)`** to be returned so that I can access the public Properties of it directly, without having to cast it first into a new variable.

In other words, I want that when I access `Class<Class>`, I'd like Goo to be returned.

I'm aware I might have not been able to explain properly so feel free to ask in the comment section so that I can try to fill in even better on what I mean. Thanks in advance!

```
class Class<T> where T : new()
{
    public T Goo;

    public Class() { Goo = new T(); }

    public static implicit operator T(Class<T> Loo)
    {
        return Loo.Goo;
    }
}

class ClassX
{
    public byte[] SharedData;

    public ClassX() { }
}

class Class2 : ClassX
{
    public byte Data;

    public Class2() { }
}

class Class3 : ClassX
{
    public string Data;

    public Class3() { }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class<Class2> foo = new Class<Class2>();
        Class2 poo = foo;

        foo.Data = 0xFF; // Error - I want this to work, tho.
        poo.Data = 0xFF; // Works - Not what I want to use.

        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

EDIT #1: Updated the code.

Comment: Something like proxy class?

Comment: If I get you right you want to be able to do `new Class<Class2>().Data = 0xFF` where `.Data` is accessing `Goo`?

Comment: I updated the code. @Diryboy Interface is not of use to me the way I want to do this. So, I guess not a proxy class, then.

Comment: @Bauss Yes, exactly!

Comment: Well it's not really possible if you want to create an instance of it. Since `.Data` will then reference the left-hand variable to that and not the new instance of `Class`. You can acces `.Data` however casting to `T` everytime like `((Class2)foo).Data` I would suggest adding a property for `Data` to `ClassX` though where the type is `object` to allow different types throughout each instance of `ClassX` avoiding generics.

Comment: @Bauss Ughh, well that's too bad. Can it seriously not be done? Your suggestion does not help me, tho, because Class2 and Class3 can have a different number of variables in them. Their nothing like each other, in any way, EXCEPT for their base; ClassX. Is there any other way for Class to inherit the Properties from type parameter T? That can be directly accessed like so: new Class<Class2>().Data

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do it quite simply as you have already instantiated it within the class.

```
Class2 main = foo.Goo
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to avoid doing.

Comment: oo yes my bad i read it wrong, your looking for a return method basically, rather than cast could you not just access the properties directly? i.e. foo.goo.property? as foo already has an initialized class as goo, so in essence your returning the initialized class from foo and then accessing the properties.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Casting it is not what I want to do. Basically, I'd like the Class<T> to inherit the Properties from type parameter T and make them accessible like so: Class<Class2> foo = new Class<Class2>(); foo.Data = 0xFF;

Comment: i think this pretty sums up the answer for inheriting a generic type, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047830/how-to-inherit-from-a-generic-parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047830/how-to-inherit-from-a-generic-parameter) ,but to be honest i'm not really sure why you need to inherit the generic type when you already have the basis to do what you require via a little bit of extra code "foo.goo.data", as you have already instantiated the generic type. as goo = the generic type which means whatever class you pass in, goo will be an instantiation of that class type.