# Generic Class:: Type Parameter <T> Property Inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, types, properties, parameters

My code:

```
class ClassX;
class Class2 : ClassX;
class Class3 : ClassX;
```

Class2 and Class3 have no association to each other whatsoever, EXCEPT for them sharing the same base class. Class2 and Class3 don't share the same properties, data types or amount of properties.

Now, what I want to be able to do is:

```
class Class<T> : T;

static void Main()
{
    Class<Class2> foo = new Class<Class2>();
    foo.Class2_Property = value;

    Console.Read();
}
```

I'm aware this code is not possible, but is there any work around?

In C++, you can use an operator overload to do this like so:

```
public : operator return_data_type const;
```

Thanks in advance.

PS: I already opened a Question about this [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32179209/how-to-return-a-property-of-the-class-instead-of-the-class-itself/32179472?noredirect=1), but I wasn't certain how to ask my question, but I am now. I left it open in-case somebody finds an answer to their question through the answers I've gotten.

EDIT #1:

I've got a Packet class that has the shared Packet properties and methods, and different packets have their own header and different content. I'm changing my packet system. Basically I want to do Packet where PacketClass is the name of the specific Packet, for example LoginInfo. LoginInfo class will contain properties:

```
public PacketHeader Header;
public string Username;
public string Password;
```

Therefore:

```
    Packet<LoginInfo> foo = new Packet<LoginInfo>();
    foo.Username = "user";
    byte[] buf = foo.ToArray(); // Part of the Packet<T> class
```

That's what I meant with that each class has it's own properties. I hope that gives you got a good idea of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You can't wrap `T` this way in C# because of difference in nature between C++ templates and C# generics. So, it is better to explain, how/when/where do you plan to use it.

Comment: I'm afraid what you suggested won't help, Sayse. I'm suggesting my idea, in which you can develop on. I don't know, I don't think it's an XY problem. I'm asking for a workaround in the main post, dcastro. @haim770 , Dennis: I updated the main post with a more clear example of what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to completely rethink your implementation, as this isn't what C# is designed to do. You can do hacky things to make this work, but it's not very pretty:

```
class Class<T> where T : new()
{
    public T Value = new T();
}
```

This creates a 'container' for your 'base' type, relying on a constraint that the type `T` must have a parameterless constructor.

Then you can do:

```
class ClassX {}

class Class2 : ClassX 
{ 
    public int test = 10;
}
```

Then you can consume your fake 'derived' class like this:

```
Class<Class2> foo = new Class<Class2>();
var test = foo.Value.test;
```

You also have to make any fields you're interested in on `Class2` public for this to work.

Comment: This isn't exactly how I wanted to solve this, but there seems to be no other way, so I'll just satisfy myself with this "work-around".

Comment: Glad to help! It's a shameless hack, but it does approximate the behavior you want at least...

Answer (score 1):

You can't do exactly what you want using C#, but you shouldn't.
Here's design issue. The packet *is not* a packet content. It *contains* some header and some content:

```
interface IPacketItem
{
    byte[] ToArray();
}

class Packet<THeader, TContent>
    where THeader : IPacketItem
    where TContent : IPacketItem
{
    // header and content must be initialized somehow;
    // maybe, using existing instances, maybe using new() constraint
    public THeader Header { get; private set; }
    public TContent Content { get; private set; }

    public byte[] ToArray()
    {
        // builds an array using IPacketItem.ToArray
    }
}

var loginPacket = new Packet<PacketHeader, LoginInfo>();
loginPacket.Content.UserName = "user";
```

Comment: I voted Baldricks response as the Answer because it's the closest implementation to what I was trying to do. Although, your implementation is an interesting perspective and also a good one, therefore I up-voted it. Thank you for your help, Dennis. I hope this answers anothers question.