# Generic Class inherit from T

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Can I inherit my class from a generic type `T`?
For example:

```
public abstract class BasePage<T> : T, IDisposable where T : Page 
{
    // Realization
}
```

I need to do this to provide basic functionality to other types of pages.

```
public class ContentBasePage : BasePage<ContentPage>
{ }

public class TabbedBasePage : BasePage<TabbedPage>
{ }
```

But I need to have ContentBasePage inherited from ContentPage, TabbedBasePage is inherited from TabbedPage. This is necessary to use this class in the Xaml markup. **I can create a shared interface IBaseType, but the code will be duplicated**

My full BasePage class, this isn't work:

```
public abstract class BasePage<T> : IDisposable where T : Page
{
    #region Private Fields

    protected BaseViewModel BaseViewModel { get; private set; }

    #endregion


    #region Init / Dispose

    ~BasePage()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        BaseViewModel?.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion


    #region Public Methods

    public void SetViewModel(BaseViewModel viewModel)
    {
        BindingContext = BaseViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    #endregion


    #region Override Methods

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        Task.Run(async () => {
            await Task.Delay(50); // Allow UI to handle events loop
            if (BaseViewModel != null)
                await BaseViewModel.OnPageAppearing();
        });
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        Task.Run(async () => {
            await Task.Delay(50); // Allow UI to handle events loop
            if (BaseViewModel != null)
                await BaseViewModel.OnPageDissapearing();
        });
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: See [CRTP in C#](http://zpbappi.com/curiously-recurring-template-pattern-in-csharp/)

Comment: Why not just give it a go? It will be pretty obvious if you can't from the compiler errors or lack there of

Comment: @sbp Yea, they have a deep hierarchy, but they are derived from a single Page class. TappedPage - MultiPage, ContentPage - Page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inherit from a generic parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047830/how-to-inherit-from-a-generic-parameter)

Comment: @sbp Th, but how can i do this without dublicate code?

Answer (score 3):

> Can I inherit my class from T class?

You cannot inherit from `T` since it is just a placeholder for a type. The compiler will not know what structure to apply because there is none.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters) says:

> a type parameters is a placeholder for a specific type that a client specifies when they instantiate a variable of the generic type. A generic class, such as GenericList listed in Introduction to Generics, cannot be used as-is because it is not really a type; it is more **like a blueprint for a type**.

You need to remove the `T` from the inheritance declaration:

```
public abstract class BasePage<T> : IDisposable where T : Page
```

But you can inherit from a generic class like in your example `BasePage<T>`. When you do this you have to specify the type of `T` in the derived class like you did:

```
public class ContentBasePage : BasePage<ContentPage>
```

Your code will work if `ContentPage` and `TabbedPage` inherit from `Page`

Comment: But I need to have ContentBasePage inherited from ContentPage, TabbedBasePage is inherited from TabbedPage. This is necessary to use this class in the Xaml markup

Comment: If ContentBasePage inherit from Page it will not work

Comment: ok your edit makes the situation somewhat different. Why do you want to use `T` for `BasePage` ? I don't see any usage of `T` inside the class? Can you explain how `BasePage` is connected to `ContentBasePage` and `TabbedBasePage`?

Comment: T never used, I just tried to have my BasePage class depending on what I needed to inherit from either TabbedPage or from ContentPage. T is like a test. Is there a workaround?

Comment: There is a solution, but for me it's bad, I created a common IBasePage interface, this interface is implemented by the ContentBasePage class, TabbedBasePage:

`public class ContentBasePage : ContentPage, IBasePage
    { //Dublicate Code}`

`public class TabbedBasePage : TabbedPage, IBasePage
    { //Dublicate Code}`

Comment: @NikitaGoncharyk so you actually want `ContentBasePage` to inherit from `BasePage` ? from your initial question I thought it would be the other way around

Comment: @NikitaGoncharyk can you describe a little more the construct that you are trying to built. I think there is a generic solution for it. What role does `Page` play in the entire context? Why is `T` supposed to be of type `Page`?

Answer (score 0):

Since the title of this question was 'Generic Class inherit from T', it looked like duplicate of this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047830/how-to-inherit-from-a-generic-parameter) but sounds like you are just after a pattern to avoid duplication (based on your comment on your own question and no reference to T in the code example of `BasePage<T>` that you put in question). In that case I wouldn't use generic. It would become simple case of inheritance. Would following solution work for you?

```
public class Page
{
    public string PageProperty { get; set; }
}
public abstract class BasePage : Page, IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}

public class ContentPage : BasePage
{
    public string ContentProperty { get; set; }
}

public class TabbedPage : BasePage
{
    public string TabbedProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ContentBasePage : ContentPage{}

public class TabbedBasePage : TabbedPage{}
```

Comment: Page, ContentPage and TappedPage this is a build-in classes in Xamarin.Forms and this will not work for me