# How is this kind of abuse of generics not ambiguous/trigger an error in the compiler

Tags: c#, .net, generics, compiler-errors, specifications

I've been feeling my way around the C# compiler with it's limits of "inherited instantiated generic classes".

Anyway, This is my test case:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new InClass();
        Console.WriteLine(x.Test(10)); //prints foo
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class BaseClass<Foo, Bar>
{
    public virtual Foo Test(Bar b)
    {
        return default(Foo);
    }
    public virtual string Test(int b)
    {
        return "foo"; ;
    }
}
class InClass : BaseClass<string, int>
{
    /*public override string Test(int b)
    {
        return "bar";
    }*/
}
```

I would think that this declaration of InClass would throw a compiler error, as it makes `Test` ambiguous. It also makes the non-generic `Test` impossible to call within the `InClass`. Notice I have some code commented out in `InClass` as well. If I uncomment that code, I do get a compiler error.

Is there a mention of this behavior at all in the C# spec, or is this an unheard of edge case?

Comment: That's awesome. In the C# spec, I believe it says "Don't do this".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would think that this declaration of InClass would throw a compiler error, as it makes Test ambiguous.

Nope. The specification calls out this kind of thing explicitly in section 7.5.3.6:

> While signatures as declared must be unique, it is possible that substitution of type arguments might result in identical signatures. In such cases, the tie-breaking rules of overload resolution above will pick the most specific member.
>
> The following examples show overloads that are valid and invalid according to this rule.

(Examples follow, obviously.)

So the language designers have considered it, but presumably the alternatives would be worse. (It would be annoying to not be able to create a class such as `InClass` even when you didn't want to call `Test`, for example.)

Comment: +1 (See Jon Skeet answer, instinctively click the upvote before reading)

Comment: Well after reading C# In Depth you know the answer is correct if not exhaustive.  "=> Pg Xyz in my book for every minutia"

Answer (score 1):

See this related question:

[Why aren't generic type constraints inheritable/hierarchically enforced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606390/why-arent-generic-type-constraints-inheritable-hierarchically-enforced)

Eric Lippert provides a thorough exploration of the potential implications.

The inherited generic types are not enforced by the compiler because they dev team felt it was a rabbit hole not worth going down.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that method with `(int x)` signature is better match for `int` argument than one with generic type `Bar` that happens to be `int` in this particular case.