# Calling base class generic type constrained method from closure created in derived causes VerificationException

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, closures

I have a base class, implementing an interface, which grossly simplified looks like this:

```
interface I
{
    void DoStuff<T>(T t) where T : class;
}

class A : I
{
    public virtual void DoStuff<T>(T t) where T : class
    {
        // do some work
        System.Console.WriteLine(t);
    }
}
```

I'm deriving from this class like so:

```
class B : A
{
    public override void DoStuff<T>(T t)
    {
        DoMoreSpecificStuff(() => { base.DoStuff(t); });
    }

    public void DoMoreSpecificStuff(Action action)
    {
        // set some stuff up before calling the action
        action();
        // tear some stuff down
    }
}
```

The specialized class is then used like so:

```
I i = new B();
i.DoStuff("Hello World");
```

This throws a `VerificationException` with **in runtime** the message `Method Constraints.A.DoStuff: type argument 'T' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.`.

The problem is fixable by either
* Making the closure `() => { new A().DoStuff(t); }`
* Creating the method `B.BaseDoStuff<T>(T t) where T : class { base.DoStuff(t); }`

I've solved it using the second option, but I'm really curious as to why this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: A haven't found any issue in the code. Can you share the .NET version?

Comment: Works for me with VS2010 / .NET 4.0. What are you using?

Comment: Have the same **runtime** issue with VS2012 / .Net4.5

Comment: ... and the answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8606679/1236044

Comment: I don't see how calling `base.DoStuff(t)` directly from the derived class is any different from calling it in a closure.