# Pass Generic Type up the Inheritance Tree

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have the following classes:

`abstract class Foo<T>`
`abstract class BaseClass : Foo<BaseClass>`
`class DerivedOne : BaseClass`
`class DerivedTwo : BaseClass`

Using this structure, all class that derive from `BaseClass` inherit from `Foo<BaseClass>`. I want to be able to set the generic type of `T` different in each derived class

For example, in `DerivedOne` I want the class to be `Foo<DerivedOne>` but in `DerivedTwo` I want the class to derive from `Foo<DerivedTwo>`.

Is there any way to pass the generic type up the inheritance tree?

I tried doing something like this (which doesn't work).

`abstract class Foo<T>`
`abstract class BaseClass<T> : Foo<T>`
`class DerivedOne : BaseClass<DerivedOne>`
`class DerivedTwo : BaseClass<DerivedTwo>`

Edit: changed generic types to show that they are passing in themselves as generic types

Edit #2: Here is a code sample of the actual classes I am using:

```
public abstract class DBObject<T> 
    where T : DBObject<T>, new()
{ 
    //the generic type is for this method, so I can create an object from a database query
    public static T Create(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        Type T = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;
        T obj = new T();

        foreach (var field in obj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            if (dataRow.Table.Columns.Contains(field.Name))
            {
                Object safeObj = Convert.ChangeType(dataRow[field.Name].ToString(), field.FieldType);
                field.SetValue(obj, safeObj);
            }

        }

        foreach (var field in obj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(field.Name + "=" + field.GetValue(obj));
            //propInfo.SetValue(obj, value, null);
        }
        return obj;            
    }
}

public abstract class Contact<T> : DBObject<T> 
    where T : Contact<T>
{ 
    //field and methods ommitted...
}

public class Person : Contact<Person>
{ 
    //fields and methods ommitted...
}

public class Company : Contact<Company>
{
    //fields and methods ommitted...
}
```

The classes can then be used in such a manner:

```
Person person = Person.Create(/* DataRow from a query result */);
```

Comment: The example you gave works perfectly, it is probably something else, why do you say it does not work

Comment: Perhaps you want `abstract class BaseClass<T> : Foo<T> where T:Bar`?

Comment: @Nobody I'm getting the following errors `The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Foo<T>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'Foo<T>'.` and `'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Foo<T>'
`

Comment: @DStanley They are passing themselves as the generic type which means it would need to be something that subclasses itself (ie. `abstract class BaseClass<T> : Foo<T> where T : BaseClass<T>`) and this gives the following error `'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Foo<T>'`

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a small code sample that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @Dweeberly I added the code I'm using. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get your code to compile if you add the `new()` constraint to `Contact<T>`:

```
public abstract class Contact<T> : DBObject<T> 
    where T : Contact<T>, new()
{ 
    //field and methods ommitted...
}
```

This is necessary since [generic constraints aren't inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606390).