# Assigning my ICollection<T> to an ICollection property

Tags: c#

Yes, I know that `ICollection` and `ICollection<T>` are two different things. Let me describe what I'm trying though...

This is what I would like to do:

```
public class SubmissionListViewModel
{
    public ICollection<ProjectSubmissionViewModel> Submissions { get; set; }

    public ReportBase GetContribAuthorsReport()
    {
        var report = new ContribAuthorsReport{ ReportType = "CSV" };

        var chapAffil = new ChapterAffiliates {ReportItems = Submissions};

        report.ReportSections.Add(chapAffil);
        // AT this point, I would expect report.ReportSections.First().ReportItems 
        // to have the records from Submissions, but I have `null`.

        return report;
    }
}
```

***Question:*** Why is `report.ReportSections.First().ReportItems` null? (See comments in code above.)

Here is how `ContribAuthorsReport` and `ChapterAffiliates` are defined:

```
public class ContribAuthorsReport : ReportBase
{
    public ContribAuthorsReport()
    {
        ReportSections = new List<ReportSectionBase>();
    }

    public override string ReportName { get { return "Contributing Affiliates' Contact Information"; } }
}

public class ChapterAffiliates : ReportSectionBase
{
    public override string ReportSectionName { get { return "Chapter Affiliates"; } }

    // This is what I have now
    new public ICollection<ProjectSubmissionViewModel> ReportItems { get; set; }

    // This won't compile
    //public override ICollection<ProjectSubmissionViewModel> ReportItems { get; set; }

    // This would compile, but breaks GetContribAuthorsReport()
    //public override ICollection ReportItems { get; set; }

}
```

I will have other classes that inherit from ReportSectionBase, that will have different models for the ICollection. I believe that this issue stems from how I have the base classes defined. (See below)

My base classes.

```
public abstract class ReportBase
{
    virtual public string ReportType { get; set; }

    virtual public string ReportName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ReportSectionBase> ReportSections { get; set; }

}

public abstract class ReportSectionBase 
{
    virtual public string ReportSectionName { get; set; }

    virtual public ICollection ReportItems { get; set; }
}
```

***UPDATE:* Final Result** - Here is what I'm using now.

```
public class ReportBase
{
    public ReportBase()
    {
        ReportSections = new List<IReportSection>();
    }

    public string ReportType { get; set; }

    public string ReportName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<IReportSection> ReportSections { get; set; }

}
public interface IReportSection
{
    string ReportSectionName { get; }

    ICollection ReportItems { get; set; }
}

public class ReportSection<T> : IReportSection
{
    public string ReportSectionName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<T> ReportItems { get; set; }

    ICollection IReportSection.ReportItems
    {
        get { return ReportItems as ICollection; }
        set { ReportItems = value as ICollection<T>; }
    }
}
```

This allows me to define a report as easy as this:

```
public ReportBase GetContribAuthorsReport
(
    ICollection<ProjectAffiliateViewModel> projectAffiliates, 
    ICollection<SubmissionAffiliateViewModel> submissionAffiliates
)
{
    var caReport = new ReportBase { ReportType = "CSV", ReportName = "Reviewers' Contact Information" };

    caReport.ReportSections.Add(new ReportSection<ProjectAffiliateViewModel> { ReportItems = projectAffiliates });
    caReport.ReportSections.Add(new ReportSection<SubmissionAffiliateViewModel> { ReportItems = submissionAffiliates });

    return caReport;
}
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: In my comments: report.ReportSections.Add(chapAffil);
        // AT this point, I would expect report.ReportSections.First().ReportItems 
        // to have the records from Submissions, but I have `null`.

Comment: You need to rewrite your question so that it *clearly* states *specifically* what it is you need.  Don't make people dig through your lines of code trying to decipher what it is you're trying to figure out.

Comment: Yes, please see my edit.

Comment: [Related?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420581/inheritance-on-a-constrained-generic-type-parameter)

Comment: Sorry James, it might be, but I don't understand enough to know how they are related. That is why I ask questions. To learn how to do it right. I already know I'm doing it wrong roryap.

Comment: Maybe you properties must be `virtual` in `ReportSectionBase` class ?

Comment: Aram, sorry, they were already virtual. Copy/Past error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you shadow the collection with `new` the method is not virtual, this means when you are using a `ReportSectionBase` variable it will not use your new collection.

The easiest way to solve this is change your abstract class to a interface, this allows you to do a explicit implementation of the base class but also expose your generic collection.

```
public abstract class ReportBase
{
    virtual public string ReportType { get; set; }

    virtual public string ReportName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<IReportSection> ReportSections { get; set; }

}

public interface IReportSection
{
    string ReportSectionName { get; }

    ICollection ReportItems { get; set; }
}

public class ContribAuthorsReport : ReportBase
{
    public ContribAuthorsReport()
    {
        ReportSections = new List<IReportSection>();
    }

    public override string ReportName { get { return "Contributing Affiliates' Contact Information"; } }
}

public class ChapterAffiliates : IReportSection
{
    public string ReportSectionName { get { return "Chapter Affiliates"; } }

    public ICollection<ProjectSubmissionViewModel> ReportItems { get; set; }

    ICollection IReportSection.ReportItems {
        get { return ReportItems as ICollection; }
        set { ReportItems = value as ICollection<ProjectSubmissionViewModel>; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your ChapterAffiliates class *hides* the ReportItems property inherited from ReportSectionBase. See the [MSDN documentation on the *new* modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx). When accessing the instance through the collection, the reference is of type ReportSectionBase. Therefore, the ReportItems property has NOT been set. The only way to access the ReportItems property of the ChapterAffiliates instance is to access it on a reference of type ChapterAffiliates.

```
ChapterAffiliates a = new ChapterAffiliates { ReportItems = Submissions};
ReportSectionBase b = new ChapterAffiliates { ReportItems = Submissions};

// a.ReportItems == Submissions; returns true
// b.ReportItems == null; returns true
// ((ChapterAffiliates) b).ReportItems == Submissions; returns true
```

To solve this, I would make your ReportSectionBase a generic class. The type argument would specify the type of your ReportItems. This way, you do not need to make the collection virtual, as it will be provided in the base class. Also, it keeps everything type safe. Which is a good thing in my opinion.

```
public abstract class ReportBase<TReportSection, TReportItem> where TReportSection : ReportSectionBase<TReportItem>
{
    public virtual string ReportType { get; set; }
    public virtual string ReportName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TReportSection> ReportSections { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ReportSectionBase<TReportItem>
{
    public virtual string ReportSectionName { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<TReportItem> ReportItems { get; set; }
}

public class ChapterAffiliates : ReportSectionBase<ProjectSubmissionViewModel>
{
    public override string ReportSectionName { get { return "Chapter Affiliates"; } }             
}

public class ContribAuthorsReport : ReportBase<ChapterAffiliates, ProjectSubmissionViewModel>
{
    public ContribAuthorsReport()
    {
        ReportSections = new List<ChapterAffiliates>();
    }

    public override string ReportName { get { return "Contributing Affiliates' Contact Information"; } }
}
```

Also, consider not exposing settable collection properties. It is not recommended in [MSDN collection guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Next question is, why doesn't this work: `public override ICollection ReportItems { get; set; }` if I use that in ChapterAffiliates class. I get compile errors with `var chapAffil = new ChapterAffiliates {ReportItems = Submissions};` since I'm trying to assign an ICollection<T> to an ICollection. But I can't define ICollection<T> in my base class, so how do I get something to do what I want?

Comment: I wanted to make ReportSectionBase generic, but then I'd have to define ReportBase as generic. `public ICollection<ReportSectionBase> ReportSections { get; set; }` would not compile.

Comment: @MKenyonII Yes, you will have to make ReportBase generic and specify the type for the report section and the report item. See my updated suggestion.