# Return different Lists at one method C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, list, return

How can I return different lists of objects at one method? I have some methods, that returns some types of Lists, and I don't know what *Parse* method should return

```
public static [Something here (IList???)] Parse(string filePath)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string recordId = lines[i].Substring(0, 2);
        switch (recordId)
        {
            case "00":

                return Parse00(lines[i]); //public static List<mainInfo> Parse00(string line);

            case "11":

                return Parse11(lines[i]); //public static List<param> Parse11(string line);

          …  
          …

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `mainInfo` inherit from `param`, or vice versa, or do they inherit from some common type?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, no there are different tables at DB

Comment: What do you want to do? In your example you are returning only the first line. I assume, that you want to parse all lines, right?

Comment: You can return `List<object>` or `List<dynamic>` then (or any other collection type), that's about it. Your code isn't altogether clear, however. The first line that matches a case in your switch statement will return something and abort the loop, is this code really representative for what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Your question about inheritance is somewhat irrelevant here. Even if they inherit, a `List<MyDerivedType>` cannot implicitly be cast to a `List<MyBaseType>`. [See this SO answer for clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420581/inheritance-on-a-constrained-generic-type-parameter). I know this is not something you've explicitly stated in your comment, but I infer that that's where you were taking this train of thought to (as would other readers, I assume)

Comment: What's the problem with IList?

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work, you need a base type that all "records" inherit from. So call it `Record`:

```
public class Record
{
    // some shared properties
}

public class ParamRecord : Record
{
    // param-specific properties
}   

public class MainInfoRecord : Record
{
    // main-specific properties
}
```

Now you can return a `List<Record>`.

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to point out to you that you would save some memory if you read lines like this.

`var lines = File.ReadLines(fileName);
foreach (var line in lines)
  // Process line`

You can learn more about this on [What's the fastest way to read a text file line-by-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line).

Furthermore, I would rename your method to ParseFile to avoid confusion and use @CodeCaster approach with creating class hierarchy. Once you have class hierarchy you can write a Factory that would do the parsing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `List<dynamic>` as a return type.
Ex:

```
    public static List<dynamic> Parse(string filePath)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string recordId = lines[i].Substring(0, 2);
        switch (recordId)
        {
            case "00":

                return Parse00(lines[i]).ToList<dynamic>; //public static List<mainInfo> Parse00(string line);

            case "11":

                return Parse11(lines[i]).ToList<dynamic>; //public static List<param> Parse11(string line);

          …  
          …

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DB.Model.param>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<dynamic>'

Comment: If this is the way to go you will have to construct a new list and add all the items from the more specific list into this more open list. You can't cast. Something like: `return xyz.ToList<dynamic>();`

Comment: return Parse00(lines[i]).ToList<dynamic>();

Comment: you can also make your method return type as object so that it can accept anything

Answer (score 0):

You need your `mainInfo` and `param`-classes to inherit the same base-class or interface:

```
interface MyInterface { ... }
class Param : MyInterface { ... }
class MainInfo : MyInterface { ... }
```

Now you can return lists of the desired types:

```
string recordId = lines[i].Substring(0, 2);
switch (recordId)
{
    case "00":
        return Parse00(lines[i]); //public static List<mainInfo> Parse00(string line);
    case "11":
        return Parse11(lines[i]); //public static List<param> Parse11(string line);
```

However your methods need to return `Enumerable<MainInfo>` or `IEnumerable<Param>` as `List` isn´t covariant which means you can´t assign a `List<MainInfo>` to `List<MyInterface>`, however you can assign the former to `IEnumerable<MyInterface>` as `IEnumerable` is covariant.

Finally as both possible return-values are assignable to `IEnumerable<MyInterface>` you could use that as return-type for your `Parse`-method.